# how to convert multiple socks proxy to multiple http proxy correspondingly

Tags: proxy, socks, privoxy

There are 2 socks proxy bind on 2223, and 3333 for example, and I want to convert them to http proxy on 2224 and 3334 respectively.

I know that privoxy is able to convert a socks proxy to a http proxy but it can only listen to one port at the same time. I tried to look through the document of privoxy but I didnt find configuration related to listen to multiple port at the same time. Did I miss it? Or is there any other options to achieve this goal.